# How to get the number of milliseconds to future time in java?

Tags: java, datetime, time, milliseconds

How can I get the milliseconds to a future time in java?

The idea is to be able to wait 10 minutes until a future time.

The code so far:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
//int year = now.getYear();
//int month = now.getMonthValue();
//int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
//int hour = now.getHour();
//int minute = now.getMinute();
//int second = now.getSecond();
//int millis = now.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND); // Note: no direct getter available.

//String myfuturedateasstring = "2014/10/29 18:10:45";
//SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
//Date myfuturedateasdate = sdf.parse(myDate);

int timeintervaldelay = 10;

Calendar myfuturedateasdate = Calendar. getInstance();
myfuturedateasdate.setTime(LocalDateTime);
     
myfuturedateasdate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeintervaldelay );
long futuredateinmilliseconds = myfuturedateasdate.getTime();


//var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
//var date2 = new Date("12/12/2010");
long millisecondstostartin = Math.abs(futuredateinmilliseconds - millis);
//var diffmilliseconds = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
System.out.println(millisecondstostartin);
```

Comment: `Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10)).toMillis()` ?

Comment: The number of milliseconds to 10 minutes from now is 1000 * 60 * 10.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol Correct. Or more self-explanatory: `Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis()` (yields 600 000).

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear. The future time, is that "in 10 minutes" or is it 2014/10/29 18:10:45 (except the latter is not in the future)? Do you want to know how many milliseconds are between now and that time, the fraction of second of that time (the three digits after the decimal point), or the milliseconds since the epoch (some 13 digit value)?

Comment: You cannot use `LocalDateTime`for a point in time. Use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`. (And please forget all about the `Calendar` class, it is so cumbersome to work with and thankfully long outdated.)

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to ask for `Instant.now().plus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli()`? Just now it yielded 1676268575957.

Comment: I still don’t know what this question is asking, and yet is has got two upvotes? I understand nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid working with `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime` only for sake of measuring time differences. There is a temporal class `Instant` representing an instantaneous point of time regardless of the place. For measuring a temporal difference, use `Duration` for time-based calculations and `Period` for date-based calculations.

```java
final Instant now = Instant.now();                       // timestamp
final Instant future = now.plus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES); // timestamp + 10 mins
final Duration duration = Duration.between(now, future); // difference (Duration)
long result = duration.toMillis();                       // difference (millis)

System.out.println(result);                              // 600000
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> wait 10 minutes

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ) )
```

## Avoid `LocalDateTime` for your purpose

> LocalDateTime.now();

I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

That class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline. It lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

## Improper syntax

> myfuturedateasdate.setTime(LocalDateTime);

(a) Do not needlessly mix the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` with their replacements, the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

(b) You cannot pass the name of a class like `LocalDateTime` as an argument. Not legal Java syntax.

(c) Before posting here, try to clean up your code to compile (if practicable).

## `Duration`

> wait 10 minutes until a future time.

In Java 19+, pass a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(java.time.Duration)).

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ) ;
Thread.sleep( duration ) ;
```

In earlier Java, pass a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) to [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ) ;
Thread.sleep( duration.toMillis() ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information that since Java 19 `Thread.sleep()` accepts a `Duration`. That’s nifty. For earlier versions my way would be `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(10);`.